# algorithm for drawing xFractal at differents depths in F#

Tags: recursion, f#, fractals

[image]

the above is the xFractal mentioned in the title of this post. I need to implement a function which allows f#sharp to draw the fractal at differents dephts using an auxilliary img_Util module. I have been advised to use the following code which allows for drawing of the sierpinski triangle at differents depths as a template:

```
    open ImgUtil

    let rec triangle bmp len (x,y) =

        if len < 33 then 
            setBox red (x,y) (x+len,y+len) bmp
        else 
            let half = len / 2
            do triangle bmp half (x+half/2,y)
            do triangle bmp half (x,y+half)
            do triangle bmp half (x+half,y+half)

    do runSimpleApp "Sierpinski" 600 600 (fun bmp -> triangle bmp 512 
    (30,30) |> ignore)
```

but i tried a lot of different things with the above as template. ive tried drawing one square in the base case. ive alse tried letting the base case be one snowflake so to speak. I can make the recursion draw the innermost element for each new depth but all else i cannot get drawn. Can anyone help me? explain the algorithm to me?

Comment: Here's a hint: the Sierpinski triangle is made up of 3 copies of itself at half size (each with some corresponding offsets compared to the original's location).  It looks like your X is made up of 5 copies of itself, each at one-third size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another hint. For Sierpiński's triangle, start with an isosceles triangle whose height and width are of unit length. That way we do not have to worry about the dimensions of the canvas on which we are drawing it. For each generation, divide height and width by two.

For your X, you would need to divide the sides by three, while the offsets for the positions of the children were described by a figure twice the size of the unit square.

Note that there is an intentional bug in the program: in the triangle case, it draws the generations emanating from the starting point twice.

```
open System.Drawing
open System.Windows.Forms

let genLoops depth scale extent figure startPt =
    let offsets dist (x, y) =
        List.map (fun (ox, oy) ->
            x + ox * dist, y + oy * dist )
    let rec aux n size pt =
        if n = 0 then
            match offsets (size / extent) pt figure with
            | [] -> invalidOp "Empty figure"
            | p::ps -> [p::ps @ [p]]
        else
            pt::offsets (size / scale) pt figure
            |> List.collect (aux (n - 1) (size / scale))
    aux depth 1. startPt

type MyForm(loops) as this =
    inherit Form()
    let bm() = new Bitmap(this.ClientSize.Width, this.ClientSize.Height)
    let mutable bitmap = bm()
    let mapToPoint(x, y) =
        Point(int(x * float(bitmap.Width - 1)),
              int(y * float(bitmap.Height - 1)) )
    override me.OnResize _ =
        bitmap <- bm()
        me.Invalidate()
    override __.OnPaint arg =
        let g = arg.Graphics
        g.Clear Color.White
        for loop in loops do
            Seq.map mapToPoint loop
            |> Seq.pairwise
            |> Seq.iter (fun (p0, p1) ->
                g.DrawLine (new Pen(Color.Black), p0, p1) )
        g.DrawImage(bitmap, 0, 0)

let triangle = [0., 0.; -0.5, 1.; 0.5, 1.]
(new MyForm(genLoops 5 2. 1. triangle (0.5, 0.))).Show()
```